# #VALUE error in custom function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my code, I'm trying to return the value of "std", but its giving #VALUE error.
The input string which I'm giving to "strng" is 3,3,3,-,3
The result i'm expecting is 7.

```
Dim strng As Double
Dim std, i As Long
---------------------------------------------------
Function defaulters(strng) As Double
std = 4
a = Split(strng, ",")
    For i = 0 To Len(strng)
      If a(i) = "-" Then
        std = std - 1
      Else
        std = std + 1
      End If
    Next i
defaulters = std
End Function
```

Comment: To debug your function, call it from a sub instead of from a worksheet cell.

Comment: `strng` must be a String not a Double! std is declared as Variant. Needs to be `Dim std As Long, i As Long`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `For` should be like this

```
For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
```

The whole thing would be :

```
Function defaulters(strng) As Double
std = 4
a = Split(strng, ",")
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
      If a(i) = "-" Then
        std = std - 1
      Else
        std = std + 1
      End If
    Next i
defaulters = std
End Function
```

Also according to your issue found in comment section, your logic in code should be updated as below

```
Function defaulters(strng) As Double
std = 4
a = Split(strng, ",")
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        If a(i) = "-" Then
            std = std - 1
        Else
            std = std + Len(a(i))
        End If
    Next i
defaulters = std
End Function
```

Comment: Tried that also, still it gives same error. Actually the issue is somewhere else in the code. If you can take up the code, and make it work, i'll be so helpful.

Comment: Thanks and that works to give answer 7 for string 3,3,3,-,3. But the same formula is not giving the answer as 5 for the string -,6,-,112,-
Instead it gives 3. I understand your code is correct, but i wanted the results should be like below.     3,3,3,-,3 is 7
15,15,-,15,50 is 7
-,40,-,-,90 is 3
-,-,-,80,80 is 3
-,6,-,112,- is 5
1,2,3,-,- is 5
-,-,-,40,- is 3
89,-,88,-,- is 3
45,-,-,-,72 is 3
-,-,-,-,45 is 3
-,-,-,-,64 is 3
-,-,-,-,- is 1

Comment: `-,6,-,112,-` >> `5` that does not follow from your posted code, so you need to explain the exact rules

Comment: So now you have found rules/logic problem in your code as you are not getting expected result from the correct code. So it could be treated as different question and you can always post a new question for different problem

Comment: @TimWilliams - Sure, let me explain. Taking example -,6,-,112,-
we shall start the total with 4 and for every character "-", the total should reduce by 1, and for every non "-" character, the total should add up by 1. Please let me know if you need any information.

Comment: Your last example `-,-,-,-,-` has 5 "-" and 4 minus 5 is -1 not 1.  Likewise `-,6,-,112,-` is 4-3=1 1+2=3, not 5

Comment: @VinodVasanthKumarPaul -  As i suggested already, you should post the logic problem in different question. Anyway check the updated answer now.

Comment: Why not `std = std + len(a(i))` in else case.  Function should return a Long and `For Each` could be handy for OP. `std`should be declared in function.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
Dim strng As String
Dim std, i As Long

Sub defaulters()
    strng = "3,3,3,-,3"
    std = 4

    a = Split(strng, ",")
    f = UBound(a) - LBound(a) + 1
    For i = 0 To f - 1
        If a(i) = "-" Then
            std = std - 1
        Else
            std = std + 1
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Was able to get sorted. Thanks Mohsen.